# Bayesian calculation in binomial

Tags: bayesian, binomial-distribution

I have the calculations

$$P(S_3=S_2)=\frac{P(S_2=2\mid S_3=3)P(S_3=3)}{\sum^3_{i=0}P(S_2=2\mid S_3=i)P(S_3=i)} = \frac{1\cdot1/8}{1/2\cdot3/8 + 1\cdot1/8}=0.4$$

I know the answer is $1/2$ which is not what I get. My problem is calculating

$$P(S_2=2\mid S_3=2)$$

I use my intuition to get $1/2$ but clearly my intuition is wrong.
The above is the classic experiment of tossing a coin hence $S$ is binomial.

Can someone please help explain why my intuition is wrong and how one can calculate this? I can't seem to put it in a Bayesian framework.

Comment: You should tell us what sequence of random variables $S_2$ and $S_3$ belong to?

Comment: It is the example of tossing a coin, where 1 if head and 0 if tails. Hence S2=2 means 2 head out of 2.